# log of summation expression

Tags: summation, logarithms, exponential-sum

I am curious about simplifying the following expression:

$$\log \left(\sum_\limits{i=0}^{n}x_i \right)$$

Is there any rule to simplify a summation inside the log?

Comment: No there is no such standard rule as far as I can remember.

Comment: Is there anything to prevent you from taking the exponential and work with the sum directly

Comment: this is one of my way to solve my own problem, just asking if this can work, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes we have asymptotics with most significant term $M \to \infty$ we do this
$$
\log(M+A) = \log(M\cdot(1+S))
$$
so that $S=A/M$ is "small" in the sense $S=o(1)$, and then
$$
\log(M\cdot(1+S)) = \log M + \log(1+S) =
\log M + S - \frac{1}{2}S^2+\frac{1}{3}S^3+\cdots
$$

reference
*G. A. Edgar*, [**Transseries for beginners**](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1285160533), *Real Anal. Exchange* **35** (2010), no. 2, 253--309.

Comment: this sounds good, but $x_i$ is i.i.d.(identical independent ) in my case.So maybe I should trt another way..?

Comment: @KennyYang Are you doing any asymptotics?  There's not much that can be said generally, but maybe for your specific problem there is?  Like, do the $x_{i}$ have finite mean/variance, and are you taking $n$ large?

Answer (score 12):

There's this:
$$\log\left(\sum_{i=0}^n x_i\right) = \log(x_0) + \log\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{x_i}{x_0}\right)\right)$$
$x_0$ must be the biggest in the series.  It didn't help me with what I'm trying to solve, but I think it answers the question.

Comment: Actually, the expression is true, irrespective of whether $x_0$ is the biggest in the series or not.

Answer (score 11):

You may note that this is equivalent to trying to solve $$\log(a+b+c)$$You realize you can't do much about $a,b,$ or $c$.

The only way this can be simplified, is if you can factor something out and then apply log properties.

A more interesting question might concern $$\log\left(\Pi_{i=0}^na_i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^n\log(a_i)$$